# Python3 doesnt detect tuple

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, syntax, tuples

I have this input:
python script.py --key '("music","aaa")' --date '("01/01/1990",0,0)'

And I do:

```
constrain = literal_eval(sys.argv[2])
print(type(constrain))
print(type(sys.argv[4]))
```

And all outputs are str while they should be tuples. The input cannot be changed!

Comment: What do you get if you add `print(sys.argv)`?

Comment: What *shell* are you using to run the command line? It sounds as if whatever you are using to invoke Python doesn't parse out the quotes, so Python is sent `"'(\"music\",\"aaa\")'"`.

Comment: I get only (class,'str')

Comment: Im using cmd of windows 10

Comment: This doesn't even run as-written, meaning your script must have more. Do you have anything else aside from import statements for `sys` and `literal_eval`? FWIW, I get tuple and str using both python 2 and 3.

Comment: Okay, you're doing something really weird in code you haven't shown us. Show us complete, runnable code that demonstrates the error when you run it the way you say you ran it.

Comment: Im using repl.it/languages/python3  and same result than in my script

Comment: Since when does repl.it even support command-line arguments?

Comment: I added the same input than here, even doing s = '("a","b")' and then checking type it says str

Comment: `s = '("a","b")'`: you're already in the python interpreter so it will work! check the command line from my answer (don't _type_ it, _copy/paste_ it)

Comment: @Dani what is "s"? if you check the type of `s` you'll get `str` of course!

Comment: @Jean-François updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're command line should work perfectly from MSYS or Linux, but here you're running it from windows shell.

Windows shell doesn't treat simple quotes as syntatcic. They're passed literally to your python code. To top it all, the double quotes are removed which makes your second arg **`'(music,aaa)'`** when passed to python: no way you can `literal_eval` that. So your input string *has* to be changed (or your operating system :))

Do this to call your code:

```
python script.py --key "(""music"",""aaa"")" --date "(""01/01/1990"",0,0)"
```

You have to quote the arguments and double the quotes in the arguments. And use double quotes exclusively.

EDIT: or even better (would work on both Linux and Windows): use simple quotes inside your arguments, double quotes outside (`literal_eval` is not `json`: it understands both simple & double quotes!):

```
python script.py --key "('music','aaa')" --date "('01/01/1990',0,0)"
```

now I'm getting:

```
<type 'tuple'>
<type 'str'>
```

(you get `str` because the 4th argument is always a string, you probably forgot to `literal_eval` it)

and `print(constrain)` yields:

```
('music', 'aaa')
```

(so it's not a python issue, rather a CMD issue)

Comment: working perfectly here. Can you paste what's your new command line?

Comment: Updated with photo

Comment: @Dani for gods' sake, don't post blurry cell phone images of your monitor. Copy the relevant text you want to show, and paste it into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information. Your photo also adds absolutely nothing to the discussion. It shows that a single-quoted string containing double quotes is correctly interpreted as a string when assigned *inside* the Python interpreter.

Comment: @Dani why can't you change the input to match what was suggested in this answer?

Comment: @Dani: you're already in the python interpreter: you have passed s as a quoted string. What do you expect. Use `literal_eval` on `s` that'll work.